# LuaJIT 2.1 (non-existent opcodes)

Tags: bytecode, luajit

LuaJIT version: 2.1.

When I try to decompile the script, I get an error. Then I saw that there are non-existent opcodes in the byte code, because of which the decompiler refuses to decompile the script.

Below I attach the script itself, as well as the bytecode from it, which I was able to get.
Also a link to the decompiler.

Download: [Script + Bytecode.](https://fex.net/ru/s/erlfryz)
[Decompiler](https://gitlab.com/znixian/luajit-decompiler).

I haven't tried anything since I don't have a computer to try what I wanted.
As an option, try putting hooks, thereby pulling the script, but without protection. But there are anti-hooks in the script, and I don't know which ones.

I am also attaching the errors that the decompiler gave out.

```
Traceback (most recent call last): 
  File "C:\Users\1\Desktop\Реверсинг\test\ljd\main.py", line 296, in <module> 
    retval = main_obj.main() 
             ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ 
  File "C:\Users\1\Desktop\Реверсинг\test\ljd\main.py", line 207, in main 
    self.decompile(self.options.file_name) 
  File "C:\Users\1\Desktop\Реверсинг\test\ljd\main.py", line 248, in decompile 
    self.ast = ljd.ast.builder.build(header, prototype) 
               ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ 
  File "C:\Users\1\Desktop\Реверсинг\test\ljd\ljd\ast\builder.py", line 28, in build 
    return _build_function_definition(prototype, header) 
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ 
  File "C:\Users\1\Desktop\Реверсинг\test\ljd\ljd\ast\builder.py", line 50, in _build_function_definition 
    node.statements.contents = _build_function_blocks(state, instructions) 
                               ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ 
  File "C:\Users\1\Desktop\Реверсинг\test\ljd\ljd\ast\builder.py", line 97, in _build_function_blocks 
    statement, line_marked_elements = _build_statement(state, addr, instruction) 
                                      ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ 
  File "C:\Users\1\Desktop\Реверсинг\test\ljd\ljd\ast\builder.py", line 447, in _build_statement 
    return _build_var_assignment(state, addr, instruction) 
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ 
  File "C:\Users\1\Desktop\Реверсинг\test\ljd\ljd\ast\builder.py", line 434, in decorated 
    assn = func(*args, **kwargs) 
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ 
  File "C:\Users\1\Desktop\Реверсинг\test\ljd\ljd\ast\builder.py", line 527, in _build_var_assignment 
    expression = _build_function(state, instruction.CD) 
                 ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ 
  File "C:\Users\1\Desktop\Реверсинг\test\ljd\ljd\ast\builder.py", line 851, in _build_function 
    return _build_function_definition(prototype, state.header) 
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ 
  File "C:\Users\1\Desktop\Реверсинг\test\ljd\ljd\ast\builder.py", line 50, in _build_function_definition 
    node.statements.contents = _build_function_blocks(state, instructions) 
                               ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ 
  File "C:\Users\1\Desktop\Реверсинг\test\ljd\ljd\ast\builder.py", line 72, in _build_function_blocks 
    _establish_warps(state, instructions) 
  File "C:\Users\1\Desktop\Реверсинг\test\ljd\ljd\ast\builder.py", line 242, in _establish_warps 
    block.warp, shift = _build_warp(state, block.last_address, warp) 
                        ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ 
  File "C:\Users\1\Desktop\Реверсинг\test\ljd\ljd\ast\builder.py", line 255, in _build_warp 
    last = instructions[-1] 
           ~~~~~~~~~~~~^^^^ 
IndexError: list index out of range

Traceback (most recent call last): 
  File "C:\Users\1\Desktop\Реверсинг\test\ljd\main.py", line 296, in <module> 
    retval = main_obj.main() 
             ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ 
  File "C:\Users\1\Desktop\Реверсинг\test\ljd\main.py", line 207, in main 
    self.decompile(self.options.file_name) 
  File "C:\Users\1\Desktop\Реверсинг\test\ljd\main.py", line 241, in decompile 
    header, prototype = ljd.rawdump.parser.parse(file_in, on_parse_header) 
                        ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ 
  File "C:\Users\1\Desktop\Реверсинг\test\ljd\ljd\rawdump\parser.py", line 36, in parse 
    r = r and _read_prototypes(parser, parser.prototypes) 
              ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ 
  File "C:\Users\1\Desktop\Реверсинг\test\ljd\ljd\rawdump\parser.py", line 75, in _read_prototypes 
    if not ljd.rawdump.prototype.read(state, prototype): 
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ 
  File "C:\Users\1\Desktop\Реверсинг\test\ljd\ljd\rawdump\prototype.py", line 49, in read 
    r = r and _read_constants(parser, prototype) 
              ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ 
  File "C:\Users\1\Desktop\Реверсинг\test\ljd\ljd\rawdump\prototype.py", line 137, in _read_constants 
    return ljd.rawdump.constants.read(parser, prototype.constants) 
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ 
  File "C:\Users\1\Desktop\Реверсинг\test\ljd\ljd\rawdump\constants.py", line 29, in read 
    r = r and _read_complex_constants(parser, constants.complex_constants) 
              ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ 
  File "C:\Users\1\Desktop\Реверсинг\test\ljd\ljd\rawdump\constants.py", line 74, in _read_complex_constants 
    complex_constants.append(parser.prototypes.pop()) 
                             ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ 
IndexError: pop from empty list
```

Comment: As the Readme says: "WARNING! This code is not finished or tested! There is not even the slightest warranty that the resulting code is even close to the original. Use the decompiled code at your own risk. SECOND WARNING! This is all a huge prototype. The "release" version should be written in Lua itself, because it's cool to
decompile the decompiler — a great test too!"

Comment: Wow!  A some kind of bytecode protection is used in this bytecode file (see the message at the end of the .luac file).  Thanks for sharing.

Comment: @ESkri, Not a bad bytecode protection, huh?  did you manage to remove it?